# Scala type hierarchy

Tags: scala, types

I looked at Scala Type Hierarchy
[image]

It's pretty clear that Unit is a subtype of AnyVal. So I tried this:

```
object Main extends App {

    val u : Unit = Seq[String]()

}
```

and it compiled fine. But I expected some error. [***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/jnqndl).

Why? `Unit` is not a supertype of a `Seq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why? `Unit` is not a supertype of a `Seq`

You are assuming that the `Seq` is assigned to `u`. But it isn't:

```
println(u)
# ()
```

As you can see, the value of `u` is `()` (i.e. the unique singleton instance of `Unit`), not an empty `Seq`.

This is due to [*Value Discarding*, which is described in clause 5 of section 6.26.1 *Value Conversions* of the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#value-discarding):

> The following seven implicit conversions can be applied to an expression `e` which has some value type `T` and which is type-checked with some expected type `pt`.
>
> […]
>
> If `e` has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`, `e` is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ e; () }`.

In plain English as opposed to "Speclish", what this means is: if you say "this is of type `Unit`", but it actually isn't, the compiler will return `()` for you.

The `Unit` type is sort-of the equivalent to a statement: statements have no value. Well, in Scala, everything has a value, but we have `()` which is a useless value, so what would in other languages be a *statement* which has no value, is in Scala an *expression* which has a useless value. And just like other languages which distinguish between expressions and statements have such things like *statement expressions* and *expression statements* (e.g. ECMAScript, Java, C, C++, C♯), Scala has *Value Discarding*, which is essentially its analog for an *Expression Statement* (i.e. a statement which contains an expression whose value is discarded).

For example, in C you are allowed to write

```
printf("Hello, World");
```

even though `printf` is a function which returns a `size_t`. But, C will happily allow you to use `printf` as a statement and simply discard the return value. Scala does the same.

Whether or not that's a good thing is a different question. Would it be better if C forced you to write

```
size_t ignoreme = printf("Hello, World");
```

or if Scala forced you to write

```
val _ = processKeyBinding​(…)
// or
{ processKeyBinding​(…); () }
```

instead of just

```
processKeyBinding​(…)
```

I don't know. However, one of Scala's design goals is to integrate well with the host platform and that does *not* just mean high-performance language interoperability with other languages, it also means easy onboarding of existing developers, so there are some features in Scala that are not actually needed but exist for familiarity with developers from the host platform (e.g. Java, C♯, ECMAScript) – *Value Discarding* is one of them, `while` loops are another.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `Unit` can also be inferred from statements (in contrast with expressions). This means that if you use the `Unit` type annotation, the compiler will ignore the last value in your expression and return  `Unit` after your actual code.

You can simply testing this, by casting your `u` back to its original type. You will get a cast error, because `u` isn't actually bound to your `Seq`.

Here's what happens if you run this in the REPL:

```
scala> u.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

As Jasper-M correctly pointed out, the compiler will rewrite this to

```
val u: Unit = { Seq[String](); () }
```

Comment: Specifically, the compiler rewrites that code to `val u : Unit = { Seq[String](); () }`. Otherwise you would have to end every `Unit` returning method with `()` for it to typecheck.